# Verificação de usuário

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um programa que tem `5 níveis de autorização`, o `Administrador`, `Gerente`, `Operador`, `Usuário` e `Convidado`. 
  Mas para cada nível ele da um acesso diferente ao sistema.

Esboço da **verificação:**

```
<?
include("../sai_clas/sai_conecta.php");
?>

    <? if($_SESSION("cb_acess_usua") == 0) {
        Chama os dados validos para o administrador!
    }
    ?>
```

No caso do código acima, o `sai_conecta.php` é o que mantém minha conexão com o Banco. Ai em seguida é efetuada a verificação para determinar se o código do acesso do usuário é igual a 0 (que no caso seria o administrador), onde se for manda todos os dados a ele permitido.

Obs: Não sei se o cod. acima está certo, é só um esboço!

Minha duvida em si é, como fazer essa verificação, para dai chamar os dados conforme o nivel de autorização!

Eu chamo essa verificação através de um menu principal, que quando o usuário selecione a opção' ele vai abrir só os dados que são permitidos a ele!

Exemplo de uma parte do **menu:**

```
<div class="menuitem" onmouseover="over(2)" onmouseout="out(2)">
    <a href="../sai_prin/menu_com_abas_dist">
    <font face="arial" >Distribuição</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloque mais informação, a sua idéia, e talvez assim como o seu sistema deva se comportar isso acho crucial, mediante as autorizações?

Comment: É ampla de mais, a sua questão, e não tem uma dúvida, especifica! é difícil compreensão e existe um fator no site quando a mesma não tem condições de resposta ou ampla de mais (como acredito ser essa) a questão pode ser fechada! Tente falar da dúvida em si...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira mais eficiente, seria você determinar a verificação dentro do menu de seleção.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="menuitem" onmouseover="over(2)" onmouseout="out(2)">
<?
    if($_SESSION['SS_cb_aces_usua']<2)
    {
    echo'<a href="../sai_prin/menu_com_abas_dist.php">Distribuição</a>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

Como você determinou no código, ao clicar na distribuição ele chamaria um menu separado. 
No cod acima ele faz uma verificação mostrando os dados somente para aqueles que tem tem autorização de 0 a 2 (não sei dizer se seria de 0 a 5 o numero que determina cada um).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode estar criando uma [lista de controle para acesso](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List), as permissões que o usuário possui baseado em seu perfil dentro do sistema. Uma biblioteca que fornece uma estrutura para isso é o [`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html).

A *ACL* é composta de três funções básicas, são elas:

1. Perfil (*Role*)
2. Funcionalidades (*Resource*)
3. Permissões (*Permissions*)

### Perfil

O código a seguir define três perfis base - `guest`, `membro` e `admin` - a partir do qual outros perfis podem herdar. Em seguida, um perfil identificado por `someuser` é estabelecido e herda os outros três perfis. A ordem em que esses papéis aparecem na array `$parents` é importante.

Quando necessário, **Zend_Acl** procura por regras de acesso definidas não só para o perfil consultado (`someuser`), mas também sobre os perfis a partir do qual o perfil consultado herda (`guest`, `membro` e `admin`):

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('member'))
    ->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

$parents = array('guest', 'member', 'admin');
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('someUser'), $parents);

$acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('someResource'));

$acl->deny('guest', 'someResource');
$acl->allow('member', 'someResource');

echo $acl->isAllowed('someUser', 'someResource') ? 'allowed' : 'denied';
```

### Criar a Lista de controle de Acesso

Uma [lista de controle de acesso](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List)(*ACL*) pode representar qualquer conjunto de objetos físicos ou virtuais que você deseja. Para efeitos de demonstração, no entanto, vamos criar um [Sistema de Gerenciamento de Conteúdo básico](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_conte%C3%BAdo) (*CMS*), a ACL, que mantém várias camadas de grupos em uma ampla variedade de áreas. Para criar um novo objeto `ACL`, nós instanciaremos o `ACL` sem parâmetros:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();
```

O *CMS* quase sempre exigirá uma hierarquia de permissões para determinar os recursos de criação de seus usuários. Pode haver um grupo `Guest` para permitir acesso limitado para demonstrações, um grupo `Staff` para a maioria dos usuários do *CMS* que realizam a maior parte das operações do dia-a-dia, um grupo de `Editor` para os responsáveis ​​pela publicação, revendo arquivamento e exclusão de conteúdo, e, finalmente, um grupo `Administrador` cujas tarefas podem incluir todos os dos outros grupos, bem como a manutenção de informações sigilosas, gerenciamento de usuários, backup e exportação.

Este conjunto de permissões pode ser representado em um *registro de perfil*, permitindo que cada grupo herde privilégios do grupo `pai`, bem como o fornecimento de privilégios distintos para apenas seu grupo único. As permissões podem ser expressas da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para este exemplo, `Zend_Acl_Role` é usado, mas qualquer objeto que implementa `Zend_Acl_Role_Interface` é aceitável. Esses grupos podem ser adicionadas ao perfil de registo como se segue:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

// Adiciona grupos para o perfil de registro usando Zend_Acl_Role 
// O guest não herda os controles de acesso
$roleGuest = new Zend_Acl_Role('guest');
$acl->addRole($roleGuest);

// Staff herda o guest
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('staff'), $roleGuest);

/*
Alternativamente, o acima pode ser escrito:
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('staff'), 'guest');
*/

// Editor de herda de Staff
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('editor'), 'staff');

// Administrador não herda os controles de acesso
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('administrator'));
```

Agora que o *ACL* contém os perfis relevantes, as regras podem ser estabelecidas que definem como os recursos podem ser acessados ​​pelos perfis. Não foi definido quaisquer recursos específicos para este exemplo, que é simplificado para ilustrar que as regras se aplicam a todos os recursos. `Zend_Acl` fornece uma implementação em que as regras só precisam ser atribuído do *geral* para o *específico*, minimizando o número de regras necessárias, porque os recursos e funções herdam as regras que são definidas sobre seus antepassados.

Conseqüentemente, podemos definir um conjunto razoavelmente complexo de regras com uma quantidade mínima de código. Para aplicar as permissões de base como acima definidos:

```
$acl = new Zend_Acl();

$roleGuest = new Zend_Acl_Role('guest');
$acl->addRole($roleGuest);
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('staff'), $roleGuest);
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('editor'), 'staff');
$acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('administrator'));

// Somente guests podem visualizar o conteúdo
$acl->allow($roleGuest, null, 'view');

/*
Alternativamente, o acima pode ser escrito:
$acl->allow('guest', null, 'view');
//*/

// Staff herda o privilégio de ver/view de guest, mas também precisa de privilégios
// adicionais
$acl->allow('staff', null, array('edit', 'submit', 'revise'));

// Editor herda os privilégios "visualizar, editar, enviar", e "revisar" de
// staff, mas também precisa de privilégios adicionais
$acl->allow('editor', null, array('publish', 'archive', 'delete'));

// Administrador não herda nada, mas é permitido todos os privilégios
$acl->allow('administrator');
```

### Consultar uma ACL

Temos agora uma *ACL* flexível que pode ser usado para determinar se os solicitantes tem permissão para executar funções em todo o aplicativo web. Realizar consultas é bastante simples, utilizando o método `isAllowed()`:

```
echo $acl->isAllowed('guest', null, 'view') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido

echo $acl->isAllowed('staff', null, 'publish') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// negado

echo $acl->isAllowed('staff', null, 'revise') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido

echo $acl->isAllowed('editor', null, 'view') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido por causa da herança de guest

echo $acl->isAllowed('editor', null, 'update') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// negado, porque não há nenhuma regra para permitir "update"

echo $acl->isAllowed('administrator', null, 'view') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido porque para administrador é permitido todos os privilégios

echo $acl->isAllowed('administrator') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido porque para administrador é permitido todos os privilégios

echo $acl->isAllowed('administrator', null, 'update') ?
     "allowed" : "denied";
// permitido porque para administrador é permitido todos os privilégios
```

Leitura complementar sobre respeito do assunto:

- [`Controle de Acesso com Zend_Acl`](http://www.johnmarques.com.br/php/controle-de-acesso-com-zend_acl/)